# Rewiring a remote control ceiling fan to be supported by separate Lutron wall switches

Tags: wiring, ceiling-fan

As part of our kitchen/dr renovation, my husband decided that he wanted our Dider 21” farmhouse ceiling fan (model 1059) to be controlled by the Caseta Lutron fan switch and light switch respectively.

Our contractor’s electrician set up the ceiling fan to be controlled by the supplied remote. We’re told that this model ceiling fan can’t be re-wired as my husband wants, because the fan has the built-in controller. In other threads on this topic, it seems like you can. My problem is that the electrician does not speak English, I do not speak Spanish and our contractor is not strong in English. But we would like to be able to explain how it can be done so the electrician can understand without the language barrier interfering.

I added the wiring diagram below. But I understand I should provide everything in writing, so:

Wires coming out of the fan and into the remote receiver: reverse (brown), fan L (black), N (white), light L (blue) There is a cap, so I assume that is where the wires coming from the receiver are joined to the fan, one to their respective color?

There are two wires coming directly from the fan, unlabeled, that go to the switch “Ground”.

There are two wires coming from the receiver AC in L (black), AC in N (white), The diagram shows AC in L (black) going to the AC in N on the switch and AC in N (white) going to the AC in L on the switch.

How would the ceiling fan need to be re-wired to be supported by the Lutron/Caseta smart switches?

Caseta/Lutron installation instructions provided:

Fan: https://www.casetawireless.com/sites/g/files/fhphhs136/files/2021-12/0301911.pdf

Light: https://www.casetawireless.com/sites/g/files/fhphhs136/files/2023-02/0301816.pdf

[image: Fan wiring diagram]

Comment: You have very clear instructions, so what is the question

Comment: It is unfortunate, however sometimes there needs to be motivation for a contractor to do the correct thing.  Show him the instruction and reinforce that you demand that those products be used.  Refuse to pay for the job unless it is completed to your desire.  If the contractor refuses.  Have another electrician come in and deduct the cost from the final draw.

Comment: What make and model is the fan in question?

Comment: 1. The ceiling fan is a Dider 21” farmhouse ceiling fan (model 1059). 

2. The fan instructions are specific to wiring the ceiling fan to the existing remote control, but we would like the electrician to wire the ceiling fan to Lutron/Caseta switches. The electrician says it can’t be done, but we believe it can be. We are looking to explain how to the electrician in a way they will understand, as the instructions do not provide alternate wiring schemes.

3. The contractor has been cooperative, they have never wired for home automation before.